# Texstudio \begin{subfigure} unrecognized command

Tags: subfloats, texstudio, subcaption

I'm using the subcaption package to make subfigures in my document like so:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/1.png}
    \caption{Subcap1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/2.png} 
    \caption{Subcap2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Cap}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This compiles fine, but in the texstudio editor, the `\begin{subfigure}` and `\end{subfigure}` are highlighted as "unrecognized command". I have tried activating the caption, subcaption, subfig and subfigure cwl files at Options > Completion but this doesn't remove the highlight.

While this doesn't affect the compiling, it is rather annoying. Am I missing something or incorrectly using the packages?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is probably better suited to the developers of TeXStudio, or perhaps one of their mailing lists or forums.  Perhaps someone here might be able to here, but this isn't strictly related to TeX or LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save this as `subcaptionTemp.cwl` in `~/.config/texstudio/` or `%APPDATA%\texstudio\`!

```
# manipulated the auto-generated subcaption.cwl for Holt
# subcaption package
# Axel Sommerfeldt 04/16/2013
# URL: http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/subcaption.html

#include:caption
#
#
# Chapter 1 Loading the package
#
#
\captionsetup[sub]{%<options%>}
#keyvals:\captionsetup
margin=%<num%>pt
margin={%<left amount%>,%<right amount%>}
margin*=%<num%>pt
margin*={%<left amount%>,%<right amount%>}
font=#scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large,Large,normalfont,up,it,sl,sc,md,bf,rm,sf,tt,singlespacing,onehalfspacing,doublespacing,{strech=%<amount%>},normalcolor,{color=%<colour%>},normal
font+=#scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large,Large,normalfont,up,it,sl,sc,md,bf,rm,sf,tt,singlespacing,onehalfspacing,doublespacing,{strech=%<amount%>},normalcolor,{color=%<colour%>},normal
font={%<option 1%>,%<option 2%>}
labelfont=#scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large,Large,normalfont,up,it,sl,sc,md,bf,rm,sf,tt,singlespacing,onehalfspacing,doublespacing,{strech=%<amount%>},normalcolor,{color=%<colour%>},normal
labelfont+=#scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large,Large,normalfont,up,it,sl,sc,md,bf,rm,sf,tt,singlespacing,onehalfspacing,doublespacing,{strech=%<amount%>},normalcolor,{color=%<colour%>},normal
labelfont={%<option 1%>,%<option 2%>}
textfont=#scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large,Large,normalfont,up,it,sl,sc,md,bf,rm,sf,tt,singlespacing,onehalfspacing,doublespacing,{strech=%<amount%>},normalcolor,{color=%<colour%>},normal
textfont+=#scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large,Large,normalfont,up,it,sl,sc,md,bf,rm,sf,tt,singlespacing,onehalfspacing,doublespacing,{strech=%<amount%>},normalcolor,{color=%<colour%>},normal
textfont={%<option 1%>,%<option 2%>}
labelformat=#default,empty,parens,simple,brace
labelsep=#none,period,space,quad,colon,newline,endash
skip=%<num%>pt
list=#false,true,no
hypcap=#false,true
indention=%<amount%>pt
position=#auto,top,above,bottom,below
#endkeyvals
#
#
# Chapter 2 The \subcaption command
#
#
\subcaption{heading}#/minipage
\subcaption[list entry]{heading}#/minipage
\subcaption*{heading}#/minipage
\setcaptionsubtype#S
\setcaptionsubtype*#S
#
#
# Chapter 3 The subfigure & subtable environments    
#
#
\begin{subfigure}{width}
# pos can be b (default: )
\begin{subfigure}[pos]{width}
\begin{subtable}{width}
\begin{subtable}[pos]{width}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subtable}
\captin@For{subtyelist}#S
#
#
# Chapter 4 The \subcaptionbox command
#
#
# inner-pos can be c, l, r, s (default: c)
\subcaptionbox[list entry]{heading}[width][inner-pos]{contents}
\subcaptionbox[list entry]{heading}[width]{contents}
\subcaptionbox[list entry]{heading}{contents}
\subcaptionbox{heading}[width][inner-pos]{contents}
\subcaptionbox{heading}[width]{contents}
\subcaptionbox{heading}{contents}
\subcaptionbox*{heading}[width][inner-pos]{contents}
\subcaptionbox*{heading}[width]{contents}
\subcaptionbox*{heading}{contents}
#
#
# Chapter 5 The \DeclareCaptionSubType command
#
#
# numbering-pos can be arabic, roman, Roman, alph, Alph, fnsymbol... (defaul: alph)
\DeclareCaptionSubType[numbering scheme]{float type}#*d
\DeclareCaptionSubType{float type}#*d
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[numbering scheme]{float type}#*d
\DeclareCaptionSubType{float type}#*d
#
#
# Chapter 6 References
#
#
\thesubfigure#S
\thesubtable#S
\p@subfigure#S
\p@subtable#S
\subref{key}#*r
\subref*{key}#*r
#keyvals:\captionsetup
subrefformat=#parens
#endkeyvals
\phantomsubcaption
# other commands
\subfigureautorefname#S
\subfigurename#S
\subtableautorefname#S
\subtablename#S
\theHsubfigure#S
\theHsubtable#S
```

Then go to your preferences and load this file:

[image]

---

I would be happy for any feedback. If this works nicely for you, I will submit it to the maintainers of TXS.

Comment: It did work! Thanks very much! Check mark clicked :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Were you able to send it to the TXS people?